# Magento Import to Custom Database Field

Tags: database, magento

[image]

I have created custom database column in magento 'wholesale_min_qty' in cataloginventory_stock_item.

[image]

Question is, I cant update the field by importing from CSV file.[image]

But it is working perfectly fine when updating from admin panel.
Any idea?
[image]

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to "import from CSV file" ?

Comment: @scrowler I'm importing from the admin panel -> system -> import & export. I thought importing by specifying the field name will be enough?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, by going to

1. Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product.
2. find the function _saveStockItem().
3. add 'wholesale_min_qty => 0' to $defaultStockData array.

This is done by hard coding to magento core file. You can try to create a module to extend the core file itself, which is a best practice.